# Why do stack variables affect text segment

Tags: c, executable, memory-layout

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A,B,C;
    return 0;
}
```

I compiled the above program using gcc 32-bit Linux machine.
I ran the `size` command result I got as follows.

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1415     544       8    1967     7af a.out
```

Then I little bit modified the above code (added some values to the local variables).

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main(void)
{
    int A=10,B=20,C=30;
    return 0;
}
```

Output using `size` command

```
   text    data     bss     dec     hex filename
   1431     544       8    1983     7bf a.out
```

1. `A`, `B` and `C` are local variabels. Before assigning values to the local variables the `text` size is 1415. But after assigning the values to the local variables the `text` size is 1431 - why?
2. Stack segment size is changing as per local variables, function parameters, and function calls this point is referred from one link then how the function call affect the text segment(please explain with example).

Comment: Try disassembling the contents of the text section and I think you'll see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

In this case the `text` segment will hold extra code for the initialization of the variables.

In the case without initial values, the stack variables will be uninitialized and will appear to hold "random" values.

Answer (score 1):

1. The initialization values of your `A`, `B`, `C` variables stored in `text` segment therefore the `text` size increased. I'm not sure why is this increased only with 2 bytes, maybe because 1 of your init values can be interpreted from 2 other values and it is some kind of compiler optimization. If somebody knows, please tell me. :-)
2. As far as I know the function call itself has no direct impact on the `text` segment size. However if you have a function call in your code what is never called then the compiler might optimize it, therefore your `text` segment size decrease.

Let's imagine the following example:

```
#define RANDOM_CONDITION 0

void main(void)
    {
       if(RANDOM_CONDITION)
       {
          func1();
       }
       else
       {
          func2();
       }
    }
```

Since the `func1()` function call is not possible because the condition never pass, always the `func2()` function executed. Therefore the `func1()` function can be removed from your `text` segment because it is not necessary.

Answer (score 1):

**You have added code** to initialize the three variables in your `main()` function, so your text segment must be bigger.

Think that those variables are local to `main()`, so they are automatic variables that take their place in the stack.  They take the values from integer literals in the code, so probably the initializations are just a move instruction with an immediate parameter to a stack pointer (or base pointer) related place in the stack.  They are not initialized in the `.data` segment, so the only way to initialize them at each entry to the `main()` function (remember that `main()` is not a special function, it's just the function the runtime calls on entry to the program) is to add code to store in the variables themselves.

If you try to optimize your compiler output, probably, as you don't use those variables anywhere, you'll get a shorter output, as the code added to initialize them is not needed anymore (the variables themselves are not used anywhere).  In my architecture (amd64/clang compiler) both samples generate the same `text` size.